# Time overlaping in sql code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------
    ***************************************************
    worker | job | starttime        | endtime
    ---------------------------------------------------
    w1     | j1  | 2014-01-02 08:00 | 2014-01-02 10:00 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    w1     | j2  | 2014-01-02 08:00 | 2014-01-02 11:00
    ---------------------------------------------------
    w1     | j3  | 2014-01-02 09:00 | 2014-01-02 12:00
  ---------------------------------------------------
    w1     | j4  | 2014-01-02 12:00 | 2014-01-02 13:00
 ---------------------------------------------------
    w1     | j1  | 2014-01-02 12:00 | 2014-01-02 13:00
```

I want the result as

***w1's j1 is 2 hours***
***w1's j2 is 1 hours***
***w1's j3 is 1 hours*** its like extra time
***w1's j4 is 1 hours***

For example, When preparing the cake, coat flour and eggs at the same time but coat eggs takes longer time.
finding total time is easy but how can I separate them ?
**Is it possible code it in sql?**

Comment: I'm not sure what your question actually is. If you just want to subtract J2's endtime from J1's end time, then that is possible - but if not, then I don't know what you're after?

Comment: Why is `j1` 2 hours and `j2` 1 hour and not `j1` is 0 hours and `j2` is 3 hours?  In other words, the ordering of the jobs is very important and you can imagine more complicated scenarios where the answer is not obvious.  If you always have only two jobs, then the answer is easy.  With more, the answer may not even be well-defined for an intuitive set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.
>   (This is also true for timeparts)

```
select worker,job, DATEDIFF(HOUR,endtime,starttime) as diff from mytable
```

Comment: what is the relation to my question ? I dont understand . please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer to handle the case where the end time is equal to a previous end time.

So here's something like what you want. We take the max end time where

- the job is not the current one and
- the end time is less than the current row's end time
- and compare that the current row's end time to determine how long the current row extends the previous job.

If that response is null, the row is the first row in the job, and in that case we just use the difference between start and end.

If the end time is equal to a previous end time, determined because the row_number is greater than one when partitioned over end time, we output zero as the time since that is the differential between this row and the previous one.

Please note that the "time" data type is limited to 24 hours so it is probably not the appropriate data type for the output.  I just used it because it produces nice looking results for the times in the example.

```
declare @times table (
    rowId int identity,
    worker varchar(10),
    job varchar(10),
    starttime datetime,
    endtime datetime
)

insert into @times (worker,job,starttime,endtime)
      select 'w1','j1','2014-01-02 08:00','2014-01-02 9:25'
union select 'w1','j2','2014-01-02 08:00','2014-01-02 11:00'
union select 'w1','j3','2014-01-02 09:00','2014-01-02 12:00'
union select 'w1','j4','2014-01-02 12:00','2014-01-02 14:22'
union select 'w1','j5','2014-01-02 12:00','2014-01-02 14:22'

select *, 
    case when 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by endtime order by starttime,endtime) > 1 then cast('0:00' as time)
    else 
        coalesce(
            cast((endtime - (select max(endtime) from @times where endtime < t.endtime)) as time),
            cast((endtime - starttime) as time)
        )
    end as differential3
from @times t
```

Comment: I edited my question. Please view it again. your way seems true but somthing missing. thanks your reply.